# if ( object != null ) instead of if ( object ) in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

Is there any reason to use `if ( object != null )` in a conditional instead of the more concise `if ( object )`. I see the former more often, but it seems like the two are equivalent and the latter shorter.

Comment: What about when `object === 0`?

Comment: or even object === false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will have an object evaluate to `false`, even though the object is not null:

```
class SomeWrapper
{
     var value: Object;

     SomeWrapper(Object value)
     {
         this.value = value;
     }

     /// Overriden method from Object, see ActionScript 3 reference
     function valueOf()
     {
         return value;
     }
}

var myWrapper = new SomeWrapper(false);

if(myWrapper)
{
    trace("myWrapper evaluates to true.");
}
else
{
    trace("myWrapper evaluates to false.");
}
```

The `else` block will execute in the example above, because `myWrapper` evaluates to `false` (its `valueOf` method returns whatever value the wrapper contained, in this case `false`) even though `myWrapper` is not a null reference. The problem is that the above does **not only** test nullability of reference, it implicitly invokes `valueOf` method, courtesy of Flash Player virtual machine. This behavior of course **may or may not be what you wanted** - do you want to test whether `myWrapper` is a null value or whether it carries a null value? (or both perhaps).

Verbosity in this case is your friend, otherwise you gain code readability in return for potential runtime errors.

Comment: Thanks for the response, specifically the analysis and example on `valueOf`. I'd also add the special comments on 0 and '' in the other answers to this excellent contribution.

Comment: @StevenXu, you are welcome. I am not sure what you would want added, but if you elaborate, I can edit it in. I think the other answers also cover things my answer does not.

Answer (score 3):

different objects are treated differently. there are some values that can never be null and might erroneously trigger false when you don't want it to.

Booleans can never be null. 
if a Boolean is defined but not given a value it is treated as false;

```
var bool:Boolean;
trace(bool); // false
bool = true;
trace(bool); // true
```

int can never be null as well.
if an int is defined but not given a value, it is treated as 0;

```
var i:int;
trace(i); // 0
trace(Boolean(i)); // false
i = -1;
trace(Boolean(i)); // true
i = 0;
trace(Boolean(i)); // false
i = 1;
trace(Boolean(i)); // true
```

Number act similar to int.
if a Number is defined but not given a value, it is treated as NaN

```
var num:Number;
trace(num); // NaN
trace(Boolean(num)); // false
num = -1.1;
trace(Boolean(num)); // true
num = 0;
trace(Boolean(num)); // false
num = 1.1;
trace(Boolean(num)); // true
```

Strings are the worst.
if a String is defined but not given a value, it is treated as null!

```
var str:String;
trace(str); // null
trace(Boolean(str)); // false
str = ""
trace(Boolean(str)); // false
str = "hello";
trace(Boolean(str)); // true
```

it is very rare in my code that i only do 'if (obj)' since most of the time there is something more specific that i truly care about.

Answer (score 1):

`if (expression)` tests the truthiness of `expression` by getting its boolean value.  Since `null` and `undefined` are both falsy, `if (object)` "works" for making sure `object` isn't null.

Problem is, though, `0`, `false`, and `''` are *also* falsy.  When you use `if (object)`, the code you're trying to keep from running when it's null would also be ignored when `object` is zero, an empty string, or the actual boolean `false`.  Often, that's not what you want.

If you can't guarantee that `object` is either null or a type *other* than string, number, or boolean (or their respective object types), then `if (object != null)` is less likely to mean something unintended.